# make a custom json sort order in python

Tags: python, json

I have this [script](http://pastebin.com/SzSHsSyk), and I have a custom json example. I need to get the complete json and save it in a file in the same position.

```
dic = {'window': set_window, 'window.screen': window_screen, 'window.navigator' : window_navigator }

json=json.dumps(dic, indent=5, sort_keys=False)
print json
```

The order at this moment is correct, and I need to print it in the same order. I have been trying for 2 days and it still fails :(( Is it possible to retain the order of the JSON object as I want it?

Comment: You shouldnt rely on the ordering of JSON, different JavaScript engines will treat the ordering differently.

Comment: You could use a list instead of a dictionary to maintain order. Anyways, can you elaborate a bit as to why you'd like to keep the order?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get the complete json and save it in a file in the same
>   position.

You shouldn't rely on position to update a file containing JSON.

First of all, it would be wise to separate the configuration you seem to store in JSON from the actual code.

So let's say you have a file containing JSON:

**config.json**

```
{
     "window": {
          "innerHeight": 886, 
          "innerWidth": 1280
     }, 
     "window.screen": {
          "availWidth": 1280, 
          "availTop": 0, 
          "availHeight": 1024, 
          "availLeft": 0
     }, 
     "window.navigator": {
          "oscpu": "Windows NT 6.3; WOW64", 
          "product": "Gecko", 
          "vendor": "", 
          "buildID": "20140923175406", 
          "appName": "Netscape", 
          "appCodeName": "Mozilla", 
          "productSub": "20100101", 
          "plugins": {
               "1": {
                    "application/sdp": {
                         "type": "application/sdp", 
                         "description": "Playing SDP-files", 
                         "suffixes": "sdp"
                    }, 
                    "name": "QuickTime Plug-in 7.7.5", 
                    "filename": "npqtplugin.dll", 
                    "0": {
                         "type": "application/sdp", 
                         "description": "Playing SDP-files", 
                         "suffixes": "sdp"
                    }, 
                    "length": 1, 
                    "version": "7.7.7.5", 
                    "description": "The QuickTime Plugin allows you to view a wide variety of multimedia content in Web pages. For more information, visit the QuickTime Web site."
               }, 
               "0": {
                    "1": {
                         "type": "application/futuresplash", 
                         "description": "FutureSplash movie", 
                         "suffixes": "spl"
                    }, 
                    "0": {
                         "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash", 
                         "description": "Adobe Flash movie", 
                         "suffixes": "swf"
                    }, 
                    "length": 2, 
                    "version": "12.0.0.43", 
                    "name": "Shockwave Flash", 
                    "application/futuresplash": {
                         "type": "application/futuresplash", 
                         "description": "FutureSplash movie", 
                         "suffixes": "spl"
                    }, 
                    "application/x-shockwave-flash": {
                         "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash", 
                         "description": "Adobe Flash movie", 
                         "suffixes": "swf"
                    }, 
                    "filename": "NPSWF32_12_0_0_43.dll", 
                    "description": "Shockwave Flash 12.0 r.43"
               }, 
               "length": 2, 
               "Shockwave Flash": {
                    "application/futuresplash": {
                         "description": "FutureSplash movie", 
                         "suffixes": "spl"
                    }, 
                    "description": "Shockwave Flash 12.0 r.43", 
                    "application/x-shockwave-flash": {
                         "description": "Adobe Flash movie", 
                         "suffixes": "swf"
                    }, 
                    "filename": "NPSWF32_12_0_0_43.dll", 
                    "version": "12.0.0.43", 
                    "name": "Shockwave Flash"
               }
          }, 
          "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0.3", 
          "language": "en", 
          "appVersion": "5.0 (Windows)", 
          "platform": "x86", 
          "vendorSub": ""
     }
}
```

What you'll need to do to update the JSON stored in the file is to read the file, use `json.loads` to load the JSON into a python dict, update anything you might want and save the output of `json.dumps` with the updated keys and values to the same file. So you'll end up having something like this somewhere in your code:

```
import json

with open('prueba.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.loads(f.read())

with open('prueba.json', 'w') as f:
    # Here I update window settings as an example
    config['window']['innerHeight'] = 1440
    config['window']['innerWidth'] = 900
    f.write(json.dumps(config))
```

Comment: not resolve my solution, because I'm very need generate new config.json very time, and have different config whit different names :(

Comment: You can merge the keys, delete old ones and update existing ones very writing to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea for how it could be done:

```
class CustomOrderStr(str):

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # Replace with whatever comparison logic you want. This just reverses order.
        return not str.__lt__(self, other)

dic = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

print json.dumps(dic, indent=5, sort_keys=True)
print json.dumps({CustomOrderStr(key): value for key, value in dic.iteritems()}, indent=5, sort_keys=True)
```

Output:

```
{
     "a": 1, 
     "b": 2, 
     "c": 3
}
{
     "c": 3, 
     "b": 2, 
     "a": 1
}
```

However I have to agree with others that if you want a custom order for JSON you're probably doing something bad.

Comment: not resolve my problem :(, your solution print different !